# fabric.js generate an image that is the same size as my canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a 1000x1000 `canvas`. I want to generate an image that is the same size as my `canvas`. The image has been generated perfectly on the desktop view but it generated 3x larger than the original `canvas` size in the responsive or mobile view. For example: if the `canvas` size is 1000, then the generated image is 3x larger(3000).

This is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('test-canvas');
    var text = new fabric.Text('Hello World');
    canvas.add(text);
    canvas.setActiveObject(text);
    canvas.renderAll();
    var image = canvas.toDataURL('png',{
        format: 'png',
        multiplier: 1,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone please assist regarding this?

Comment: Why are there _two_ includes for `fabric.js`?

Comment: It was my mistake, I have updated the code. Can you please give me a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code it works for me

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(canvas.toDataURL('png'),function (img) {
     img.set({
            top: imageTop,
            left: imageLeft,
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1,
            width: 1000,
            height: 1000,
     });                            
});
```